# SSL certificate needed for a web-to-desktop websockets communication?

Tags: ssl, websocket, certificate

I'm trying to communicate a web application with a desktop application and I'm trying websockets.

The desktop application will be the websocket server, and the web application is the client.

Customers will have to download the desktop app (available for Mac, Windows and Linux) and install in their own computer. The desktop application is just a 'print server' to print POS tickets directly, without browser's confirmation, open cash drawer, etc.

So, the websocket client will connect to wss://127.0.0.1 (own user desktop).

Ok, the application is working perfectly with a self signed SSL certificate, but... Is it enough for production?

I mean... What type of certificate do I need for this? Can I buy a SSL certificate for the 127.0.0.1 address?

Can I use a free self-signed certificate? Do browsers accept it?

I have developed the server desktop application for Mac, Windows and Linux (and the web app for the client side) and just need a proper certificate to release the service!

Comment: I have the same issue. Wondering if you found a solution to this?